# ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred on docker container

Tags: python, django, oracle, docker

Im building a project which connect to a oracleDB remotely using a VPN,
the backend is python with django and I dockerized the project
until fridays last week everything was working well, after that when i run `docker compose up` I get this error:
`django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred`

The dockerfile has following structure:

```
FROM python:3.10.12-alpine3.18

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk add --update --no-cache\    
    build-base jpeg-dev zlib-dev libjpeg\
    gettext\
    py3-lxml\
    py3-pillow\
    openldap-dev\
    python3-dev\
    gcompat\
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN apk add --no-cache libaio libnsl libc6-compat curl bash

WORKDIR /opt/oracle

RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    rm -f instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    cd instantclient* && \
    rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *jar uidrvci genezi adrci && \
    mkdir /etc/ld.so.conf.d && \
    echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf

RUN ldconfig /etc/ld.so.conf.d

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_11
ENV PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_11:$PATH

RUN echo 'INPUT ( libldap.so )' > /usr/lib/libldap_r.so
```

The DB connection is:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.oracle",
        "NAME": (
            f"{env('DATABASE_SERVER')}:{env('DATABASE_PORT')}/{env('DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME')}"
        ),
        "USER": env("DATABASE_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": env("DATABASE_PASS"),
    }
}
```

What seems more strange to me is that I can perfectly connect to the DB via DBeaver (client) and another test is that I pinged the IP of the DB server and I have a response but, if I enter the container via `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID sh` and I ping the IP of the DB server I have no response.

Could someone have a solution that I can try and the reason for this error?